# When using an ADSL connection the website does not show pictures

Tags: networking, router, routing, azure

I am running a website on Azure web services when using an ADSL connection the website does not show the pictures, but when changing the connection it works just fine.

Opening the website with other computers and other browsers does not help.

I've pinged 8.8.8.8 to check a DNS/connection problem, there was no problem with it.

What could be causing the problem?

Comment: Where are the pictures stored – is it the same server or is it a CDN?